# Emberjs controller needs is not updating views

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js

I have a controller which holds messages to display in various templates:

```
var MessageController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  login: []
});

module.exports = MessageController;
```

In another controller I use `needs: ['message'], messages: null, messagesBinding: 'controllers.message.login'`. I add messages to the messages object in some actions, it works the first time I add a message. But the second time I try to add a message (in a new action) it is not updating the template.

How can I render the template again so it shows the new messages?

Comment: could u setup a fiddle to show this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't define both `messages` and `messagesBinding`. Defining a property as

```
fooBinding: 'someProperty'
```

will tell Ember to bind the value of `someProperty` to `foo`, so that `foo === someProperty` at all times.

Therefore, this will work:

```
App.SomeOtherController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: ['message'],
  messagesBinding: 'controllers.message.login'
});
```